# android autocompletetext on multiple fields of an object

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a custom java object with two string fields, name and mail.
I want an autocompletetext that is able to search on both so that if I type a partial name I see in the dropdown both name and mail, the same if I type part of the mail address.
I managed to create a custom adapter that shows both fields in the dropdown with a custom row layout, but I can't understand how to filter on both fields for autocompletion.